# how to delete seletected row from list

Tags: c#

This is my code what should I add to it to delete a paricular row from It not from database. Plz suggest that what should I write in OnRow DeleteCommand to delete . I am new to c# so Plz suggest with elaboration .

```
private List<Cart> PopulateData()
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = (DataTable)Session["Test"];
   List<Cart> Product = new List<Cart>();
   if (Session["key"] == null)
   {
       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           string Quantity = Request.QueryString["Quantity"];
           float f_num = float.Parse(row["ProductPrice"].ToString());
           Cart cr = new Cart();
           Product.Add(new Cart { ProductName = row["ProductName"].ToString(), ProductPrice = f_num, Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity), Type = row["Type"].ToString() });
       }
   }
   else if(Session["key"]!=null)
   {
       Product = (List<Cart>)Session["key"];
       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           string Quantity = Request.QueryString["Quantity"];
           float f_num = float.Parse(row["ProductPrice"].ToString());
           Cart cr = new Cart();
           Product.Add(new Cart { ProductName = row["ProductName"].ToString(), ProductPrice = f_num, Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity), Type = row["Type"].ToString() });
       }
   }
   Session["key"] = Product.Select(x => new { Quantity = x.Quantity, ProductName = x.ProductName, ProductPrice = x.ProductPrice }).Distinct();
   return Product;
}

private void BindDataList(List<Cart> dt)
{
    gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    gridview1.DataBind();
}

int m = 0;
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure the current GridViewRow is a data row. 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label Subtotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
        //Label lblUnitsInStock = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUnitsInStock");
        m = m + int.Parse(Subtotal.Text);
        //Table tb = new Table();
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label lbltotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Subtotal");
        lbltotal.Text = m.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to delete the row from the Grid, you could just use gridview1.DeleteRow(gridview1.SelectedIndex) as demonstrated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Vikash This example also delete from database

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
}
```

Comment: Consider commenting/explaining how to use your code and why does it solve the problem. Just the code without explanations is not sufficient for a good answer.